# My total_final value not working and Button too

Tags: javascript, html

My first problem is my for loop not working, I'm trying to get my final total value from the two rows total by adding both of them up. And my second problem is when I press my button it's not executing my function calculateTotal().

- been learning javascript for around 4 weeks and I guess I still count as a beginner and I'm not very good with javascript

```js
function calculateTotal() {

  // first row //
  var Unit_Price_1 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_1').value;
  var Quantity_1 = document.getElementById('Quantity_1').value;
  var Total_1 = document.getElementById('Total_1')
  var Total_Amount_1 = Unit_Price_1 * Quantity_1;
  Total_1.value = Total_Amount_1

  // Second row //
  var Unit_Price_2 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_2').value;
  var Quantity_2 = document.getElementById('Quantity_2').value;
  var Total_2 = document.getElementById('Total_2')
  var Total_Amount_2 = Unit_Price_2 * Quantity_2;
  Total_2.value = Total_Amount_2

  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      total += pareseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total_final').value = total;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!---------------- ROW 1 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_1" oninput="calculateTotal()" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_1" oninput="calculateTotal()" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_1" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <!---------------- ROW 2 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_2" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_2" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_2" />
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <input type="button" style="background-color: white" value="Calculate Grand Total Price" id="click me" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="number" name="total_final" id="total_final" value="0.00" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: silver" readonly="readonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a typo. it is "parseInt" not "pareseInt"

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in          `total += pareseInt(arr[i].value);` It is `parseInt`.
I ran your code and it is working fine.

Comment: Thankksss , but for my button not working tho im trying to ( when I press the button it will calculate the total for each row and also finally the final total ) and thanks again opps silly mistake

Comment: But what you want to do on button click, you are already doing that when typing in the fields. So the button is left with nothing as the result has already been given. Button click just runs the same function again which will have no effect.